# vhdl altera digital clock

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga

I'm working on  digital clock using VHDL Altera board. And I've got stuck during coding. I was trying to make a digital clock that shows hours, minutes, and seconds on six 7-segments. My code is like this:

---

```
 library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity time_main is
 port(clk_50mhz, reset, min_sw, hour_sw: in std_logic;     

   fnd_s: out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);    
   fnd_d: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));   
end time_main;

architecture clock of time_main is

 signal clk_cnt: integer range 0 to 50000000;      
 signal data1, data3, data5, temp: integer range 0 to 9;   
 signal data2, data4: integer range 0 to 5;                
 signal data6: integer range 0 to 2;                       

 signal cnt: integer range 0 to 5;                         
 signal clk_test: integer range 0 to 5000000000; 

 variable decode_seg: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

  begin
   case count_seg is                    
   when 0 => decode_seg := "00111111";
   when 1 => decode_seg := "00000110";
   when 2 => decode_seg := "01011011";
   when 3 => decode_seg := "01001111";
   when 4 => decode_seg := "01100110";
   when 5 => decode_seg := "01101101";
   when 6 => decode_seg := "01111101";
   when 7 => decode_seg := "00100111";
   when 8 => decode_seg := "01111111";
   when 9 => decode_seg := "01101111";
   when others => decode_seg := "00000000";
  end case;
 return(decode_seg);       
end dis_7_seg;


 begin   

  process(clk_50mhz)
   begin
    if(clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1') then                 
     if(clk_cnt = 50000000) then    
      clk_cnt <= 0;
     else
      clk_cnt <= clk_cnt + 1;
     end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  sec_1: process(clk_50mhz, reset)
   begin
    if(reset = '0') then      
     data1 <= 0;
    elsif(clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1') then   
     if(clk_cnt = 50000000) then
      if(data1 = 9) then
       data1 <= 0;
      else
       data1 <= data1 + 1;
      end if;
     end if;
    end if;
  end process;

 sec_10: process(clk_50mhz, reset)
   begin
    if(reset = '0') then        
     data2 <= 0;
    elsif(clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1') then         
     if(clk_cnt = 50000000) then
      if(data1 = 9) then
       if(data2 = 5) then
       data2 <= 0;
       else
       data2 <= data2 + 1;
      end if;
     end if;
    end if;
   end if;
  end process;

  min_1: process(clk_50mhz, reset)
   begin

    if(reset = '0') then          
     data3 <= 0;
    elsif(min_sw = '1') and (clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1') then    
     if(clk_cnt = 50000000) then
      if(data3 = 9) then
       data3 <= 0;
      else
       data3 <= data3 + 1;
      end if;
     end if;                                                    
    elsif(clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1') then         
     if(clk_cnt = 50000000) then
      if(data1 = 9 and data2 = 5) then
       if(data3 = 9) then
        data3 <= 0;
       else
        data3 <= data3 + 1;
       end if;
      end if;
     end if;
    end if;
   end process;

  min_10: process(clk_50mhz, reset)
   begin
    if(reset = '0') then       
     data4 <= 0;
    elsif(min_sw = '1') and (clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1') then   
     if(clk_cnt = 50000000) then
      if(data3 = 9) then
       if(data4 = 5) then
        data4 <= 0;
       else
        data4 <= data4 + 1;
       end if;
      end if;
     end if;                                                    
     if(clk_cnt = 50000000) then
    elsif(clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1') then                     
     if(clk_cnt = 50000000) then
      if(data1 = 9 and data2 = 5 and data3 = 9) then
       if(data4 = 5) then
        data4 <= 0;
       else
        data4 <= data4 + 1;
       end if;
      end if;
     end if;
    end if;
        end if;
  end process;

  hour_1: process(clk_50mhz, reset)
   begin
    if(reset = '0') then        
     data5 <= 0;
    elsif(hour_sw = '1') and (clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1') then       
      if(clk_cnt = 50000000) then
      if(data5 = 3 and data6 = 2) then
       data5 <= 0;
      elsif(data5 = 9) then
       data5 <= 0;
      else
       data5 <= data5 + 1;
      end if;
     end if;                                                    
    elsif(clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1') then        
     if(clk_cnt = 50000000) then
      if(data1 = 9 and data2 = 5 and data3 = 9 and data4 = 5) then
       if(data5 = 3 and data6 = 2) then
        data5 <= 0;
       elsif(data5 = 9)then
        data5 <= 0;
       else
        data5 <= data5 + 1;
       end if;
      end if;
     end if;
    end if;
   end process;

  hour_10: process(clk_50mhz, reset)
   begin
    if(reset = '0') then              
     data6 <= 0;
    elsif(hour_sw = '1') and (clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1') then  
     if(clk_cnt = 50000000) then
      if(data5 = 3 and data6 = 2) then
       data6 <= 0;
      elsif(data5 = 9) then
       data6 <= data6 + 1;
      end if; 
     end if;                                                     
    elsif(clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1') then     -
     if(clk_cnt = 50000000) then
      if(data1 = 9 and data2 = 5 and data3 = 9 and data4 = 5) then
       if(data5 = 3 and data6 = 2) then
        data6 <= 0;
       elsif(data5 = 9) then
        data6 <= data6 + 1;
       end if;
      end if;
     end if;
    end if;
   end process;

  process(clk_50mhz)
   begin
    if(clk_50mhz'event and clk_50mhz = '1') then                  
     if(clk_test = 5000000000) then    
      clk_test <= 0;
     else
      clk_test <= clk_test + 1;
     end if;
    end if;
  end process;

 process(clk_test)
   begin
    if(clk_test = 5000000000) then    
     if(cnt = 5) then
      cnt <= 0;
     else
     cnt <= cnt + 1;
    end if;
   end if;
 end process;

  process(data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, cnt)
   begin

     If (cnt=0) then
      fnd_s <= "000001";  
      temp <= data1;
     else if(cnt=1) then
       fnd_s <= "000010";  
       temp <= data2;
     else if (cnt=2) then
       fnd_s <= "000100";  
       temp <= data3;
     else if (cnt=3) then 
       fnd_s <= "001000";  
       temp <= data4;
     else if (cnt=4) then
      fnd_s <= "010000";  
      temp <= data5;
     else if (cnt=5) then
      fnd_s <= "100000";  
      temp <= data6;     
     end if;
    end if;
   end if;
  end if;
  end if;
  end if;
   end process;


  fnd_d <= dis_7_seg(temp);  

  end clock;
```

========================================================================

however, the i found out that the first segment did not show anything, just total OFF... and I found that other 5 segments show the same number: from 0 to 9 for 9 seconds, and then the segments show 0 again and keep counting from 0 to 9. I thought I made a good code enough to make hours, minutes, and seconds... but it shows only seconds.... Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code.. please?

Comment: Well, to start the code is broken: The "dis_7_seg" function declaration is partially missing. Then all clocked processes could be combined to one. Then you seem to have clock-gate logic in you design. Etc.

Comment: Can you provide link to page with "VHDL Altera board"?

Comment: In addition to JHBonarius' missing function body *function specification*, `clk_test` is declared with an right bound value that has one extra 0, process min_10 has an unexpected `if clk_cnt = 50000000 then` precediing an `elsif` and it's matching `end if` that should be removed, there's an extraneous '-' after a `then` that should be removed. All of these would prevent your code from analyzing, elaborating, and simulating or (hopefully) synthesizing. The functionality can't be validated without a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You could also note process sec_1 counts 50 MHz clocks directly, which means your clock display would never be valid.

Comment: @Staszek i'm sorry that i couldn't find the board link. Probably because of my poor internet searching skill.... all I have is the manual pdf and the picture that i'm using.... Will this be helpful? The IC i'm using is EP4CE22F17C6.   [link](ftp://ftp.altera.com/up/pub/Intel_Material/Boards/DE0-Nano/DE0_Nano_User_Manual.pdf)

Comment: Well, I just wanted to point out, that there is nothing like "VHDL Altera board". It seems from PDF that you provided, that you have DE0 Nano board. When you write "I have VHDL Altera board" you give us almost no information about your hardware. You have to be more accurate. VHDL is just language, that you use to write your design, Altera is (actually was, now it is Intel) FPGA manufacturer, and board is... board:)